# Having problem with Authorization in vuejs vuex stores

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am writing code to call api using axios. So, for this code I have to send an otp to the api along with an authorization token. I am using vuex store.
I am getting an error of 406(not applicable). This is the code I have written.

```js
import { isAuthenticated } from './auth'
import axios from 'axios'

export default ({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  getters: {

  },
  actions: {
    VERIFY: (payload) => {
      const userId = isAuthenticated().user._id
      return axios
        .post(apilink, payload, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${isAuthenticated().token}`,
            Accept: 'application/json'
          }
        }).then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          return response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error)
          }
        })
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

```html
<template>
<mdb-btn color="info" @click="verify()">Verify</mdb-btn>
</template>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js">
  data () {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    verify () {
      this.$store.dispatch('VERIFY', {
        otp: this.value
      }).then(success => {
        console.log(success)
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

I think it's the problem with authorization part. Please help me.

Comment: Can you provide more code about `isAuthenticated()` ?

Comment: I have added the snnipet

Answer (score 0):

isAuthenticated is funtion used to get data from localStorage

```js
export const isAuthenticated = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('auth')) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'))
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

406 error is appearing because of Accept parameter in the header try after removing "Accept: 'application/json'"